# Appending an array to an array using a function in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to append an array to an array using a function but it seems to return None.

Code (now works):

```py
import random
arr = []
def randomarr():
    t = []
    for i in range(3):
        r = random.randint(1,9)
        t.append(r)
    return t
for i in range(3):
    arr.append(randomarr())
print(matrix)
```

Edit: Solved by adding a return. Shame on me for forgetting to put a return statement in my code.

Comment: What does `randomarr` return?

Comment: Okay, the function indeed seems to return `None`. What part of your code is intended to cause it to return something other than `None`?

Comment: this is the most random algorithm ive ever seen. ... you are printing something that doesnt even exist in your code

Comment: sorry, I updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

Your funtion `randomarr` needs a `return` staterment.

try:

```
def randomarr():
    t = []
    for i in range(3):
        r = random.randint(1,9)
        t.append(r)
    return t
```

Comment: I could even make this a one-liner `return [random.randint(1, 9) for i in range(3)]`.

Answer (score 0):

randomarr() is not retuning anything, is just printing t.
use return like this:

```
    import random
    arr = []
    def randomarr():
        t = []
        for i in range(3):
            r = random.randint(1,9)
            t.append(r)
        return t
    for i in range(3):
        arr.append(randomarr())
    print(arr)
```